# How to download PDF with selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to download a PDF in Python using Selenium WebDriver. However, for some reason I cannot select / click the download button. It might be due to the fact that the button is not focusable?

This is the button: 
[image]

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="spinner-third" class="svg-inline--fa fa-spinner-third fa-w-16 fa-icon menubar-h-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M456.433 371.72l-27.79-16.045c-7.192-4.152-10.052-13.136-6.487-20.636 25.82-54.328 23.566-118.602-6.768-171.03-30.265-52.529-84.802-86.621-144.76-91.424C262.35 71.922 256 64.953 256 56.649V24.56c0-9.31 7.916-16.609 17.204-15.96 81.795 5.717 156.412 51.902 197.611 123.408 41.301 71.385 43.99 159.096 8.042 232.792-4.082 8.369-14.361 11.575-22.424 6.92z"></path></svg>
```

And here is my current code to reproduce:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

website = "https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/jofi.12895"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(website)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: You might want to just download the file, without using selenium.

Comment: This is just an example, so I want to understand how it works with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.rc-reader-frame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "menu-button.download span"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='rc-reader-frame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//menu-button[@class='download']//span[text()='PDF']"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: download]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: I had to edit the second line a bit, but then it worked! {WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//menu-button[@class='download']"))).click()}

Comment: @user27074 I suspected that there might be some difference between the DOM rendered within my setup and the DOM you are seeing as there was a visual mismatch. But, I was sure the answer will take you closer. Glad to be able to help you out !!!